# ATR Trailing not activating correctly after Take Profit

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to code a ATR Trailing Stop that activates after take profit is reached but for some reason it doesn't work correctly.

Here is a screenshot of an example:

[image: honey pot means long condition is true, long is then opened and TP is set at 0.20% from entry. After TP is hit, ATR Trailing stop loss is activated and should start trailing, you can't see in the image but Trailing plot is fix on 0 but somehow it lockes some profit a few bars later, even though it should close the trade at break even.]

Here is the snippet of code:

```
//STOP LOSS

//Numer of candles lookback for stop loss
LastXcandles = input.int(defval = 50, title = "Stop Loss", tooltip = "Set SL at lowest/highest of x candles back", group = "STOP LOSS")

//Find last lower low
lowestValue  = ta.lowest(LastXcandles)
LowestCandle = ta.valuewhen(ComboConditionLong, lowestValue, 1)

//Find last higher high
highestValue  = ta.highest(LastXcandles)
HighestCandle = ta.valuewhen(ComboConditionShort, highestValue, 1)

//Figure out stop loss price
LSL  = LowestCandle
SSL  = HighestCandle

//Plot stop loss values for confirmation
plot(LongOpen ? LSL : na, style = plot.style_cross, color = color.red, linewidth = 1, title = "Long SL")
plot(ShortOpen ? SSL : na, style = plot.style_cross, color = color.red, linewidth = 1, title = "Short SL")

//TAKE PROFIT

//Percentage of take profit for long and shorts
longProfitPerc = input.float(defval = 0.2, title = "Long Take Profit (%)", minval = 0.0, step = 0.01, tooltip = "Percentage of Long Take Profit", group = "TAKE PROFIT") / 100
shortProfitPerc = input.float(defval = 0.2, title = "Short Take Profit (%)", minval = 0.0, step = 0.01, tooltip = "Percentage of Short Take Profit", group = "TAKE PROFIT") / 100

//Figure out take profit price
LongTP  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + longProfitPerc)
ShortTP = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - shortProfitPerc)

//Plot take profit values for confirmation
plot(LongOpen ? LongTP : na, color = color.green, style = plot.style_linebr, linewidth = 1, title = "Long Take Profit")
plot(ShortOpen ? ShortTP : na, color = color.green, style = plot.style_linebr, linewidth = 1, title = "Short Take Profit")

//BREAK-EVEN STOP LOSS

//Conditions to use for break even stop loss identification
LongCondition  = (ComboConditionLong and strategy.position_size == 0 and not signalPlotted[1])
ShortCondition = (ComboConditionShort and strategy.position_size == 0 and not signalPlotted[1])

//Check if strategy reduced position size in last bar
longClose = strategy.position_size < strategy.position_size[1]
shortClose = strategy.position_size > strategy.position_size[1]

//Initialise variables
var float LongSL = 0.0
var float ShortSL = 0.0

//When not in position, set stop loss using close price which is the price used during backtesting
//When in a position, check to see if the position was reduced on the last bar
//If it was, set stop loss to position entry price. Otherwise, maintain last stop loss value
LongSL := if LongOpen and ta.barssince(longClose) < ta.barssince(LongCondition)
    strategy.position_avg_price
else if LongOpen
    LongSL[1]
else
    close - LSL

ShortSL := if ShortOpen and ta.barssince(shortClose) < ta.barssince(ShortCondition)
    strategy.position_avg_price
else if ShortOpen
    ShortSL[1]
else
    close + SSL

//Plot break even stop loss values for confirmation
plot(LongOpen and not LSL ? LongSL : na, style=plot.style_cross, color=color.red, linewidth=1, title = "Long SL")
plot(ShortOpen and not SSL ? ShortSL : na, style=plot.style_cross, color=color.red, linewidth=1, title = "Short SL")

// TRAILING STOP

//Boolean variables for LongTP and ShortTP
var bool LongTPReached  = na
var bool ShortTPReached = na

// Set LongTP and ShortTP conditions
if LongOpen and close <= LongTP
    LongTPReached := true
else
    na

if ShortOpen and close <= ShortTP
    ShortTPReached := true
else
    na
// Reset LongTPReached and ShortTPReached once the take profit is reached
if (LongTPReached and close[1] <= LongTP)
    LongTPReached := na

//Trailing stop based on ATR
ATRperiod = input.int(9, title = "ATR period", tooltip = "Number of candles to calculate Average True Range on")
ATRmultiplier = input.float(defval = 2.5, step = 0.1, title = "ATR multiplier", tooltip = "Number of times to multiply ATR period")

//Calculate ATR and ATR trailing
ATR = ta.atr(ATRperiod)
ATRtrailing = ATR * ATRmultiplier

//Determine trail stop loss prices
longStopPrice = 0.0
shortStopPrice = 0.0

longStopPrice := if LongOpen 
    stopValue = close * (1 - ATRtrailing)
    math.max(stopValue, longStopPrice[1])
else
    0

shortStopPrice := if ShortOpen
    stopValue = close * (1 + ATRtrailing)
    math.min(stopValue, shortStopPrice[1])
else
    999999

//Plot trailing for visual confirmation
plot(LongOpen ? longStopPrice : na, color=color.new(#690869, 0), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, title="Long Trail Stop")
plot(ShortOpen ? shortStopPrice : na, color=color.new(#690869, 0), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, title="Short Trail Stop")

//if long condition is met, open long position
if (LongCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long Entry", strategy.long)

//if long position is opened, set take profit and initial stop loss
if (LongOpen)
    strategy.exit("Long TP/BE", from_entry = "Long Entry", qty_percent = 75, limit = LongTP, stop = LSL, comment_profit = "Long TP!", comment_loss = "Long SL!")

//if in long position and tp was hit, set stop loss at break even
if (LongOpen and LongTPReached)
    strategy.exit("Long BE", from_entry = "Long Entry", qty_percent = 100, stop = LongSL, comment_loss = "Long BE!")

//if in long position and tp was hit, activate trailing stop
if (LongOpen and close >= LongTP)
    strategy.exit("Long Trailing", from_entry = "Long Entry", qty_percent = 100, limit = longStopPrice, stop = longStopPrice, comment_trailing = "Long Trailing!")
```

**I think the problem is around the calculation of ATR Trailing Stop and how to call it into action in strategy.exit function.
Another problem (that I haven't been able to resolve yet) is the var bool "LongTPReached", that after debugging I found out that it returns true every other bar after the TP is hit, while it should return true only on the bar in which occured the take profit.**

I tried modifying if statements for strategy exit, for example, I separated the TP and SL in different calls so after long take profit the stop loss would move to break even in case of a reverse and if it didn't hit the stop loss it would activate the trailing stop.

I tried using same ids for strategy exit, so I thought the calls would be made for the same position but it didn't work, it just made a mess out of it.

I tried changing strategy.exit into strategy.order and adding strategy.oca.reduce to call the reducing of the position when take profit was hit but I don't know how to really use it and never needed to, still I wanted to give it a go.